# CodeIgniter not routing requests past /index.php/ to correct controller

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

New to CI, so it's probably safe to assume misunderstandings...

My folder structure looks like

```
.
└── www
    ├── appthing
    │   └── V5
    │       ├── application
    │       │   ├── config
    │       │   ├── controllers
    │       │   │   ├── api
    │       │   │   └── V1
    │       │   │       ├── settings.php
    │       │   ├── ...
    │       │   └── views
    │       └── system
    └── vhosts
        └── appthing
              index.php
              .htaccess
```

[htaccess](https://gist.github.com/philipptempel/4226750)

My apache config in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf looks like:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/www/vhosts/appthing

 <Directory "/var/www/www/vhosts/appthing">
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
```

When I navigate to `ipaddress/index.php` I get an authentication error, which is good, since I can at least access the index.php file. However, if I try to go to `index.php/settings` I get a CI 404 error. The same code works on my computer (OS X, trying to put it on a AWS Ubuntu 16 instance currently), so it's not a problem with CI semantics.

Comment: What is your default controller in config/routes `$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';` change it to your controller location `/api/controller_name/function_name_if_you_want_function_as_Default`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set your Documentroot to /var/www/www/appthing/V5. Normally you should have and index.php file in your CI project which will redirect you to a home (standard = welcome.php) controller.